# Help writing a data explorer query

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to (eventually) write a query to give me number of upvotes per day for a given tag.  Unfortunately I'm having trouble getting off the ground.  Right now I'm just trying to get **answers** I've written for questions tagged JavaScript

```
select * 
from Posts 
where Posts.PostTypeId = 2 and 
     (EXISTS 
       (select 1 
        from PostTags where PostTags.PostId = Posts.ParentId and PostTags.TagId = 3))
     and Posts.OwnerUserId = 352552
```

This does seem to give me javascript answers I've written, but only 7 of them; I have much, much more than that.

And this similar attempt produces the same:

```
select * 
from Posts 
where Posts.PostTypeId = 2 and ParentId IN
       (select PostId 
        from PostTags where PostTags.TagId = 3)
     and Posts.OwnerUserId = 352552
```

Clearly I'm making at least one invalid assumption about the data model.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [most of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:352552%20%5Bjavascript%5D) in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag were posted very recently. However, the data explorer does not point to the real time data. The data explorer that you are querying against contains data up to `September 2011`. So, if you had only answered 7 questions in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag before *September 2011*, then you are going to see only those 7 records.

Check the following link for cc-wiki-dump releases:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/